# Mediawiki automatic "translation", creation of new pages

Tags: translation, mediawiki, transliteration

Required is creation of automatically "translated" (using in-house set of rules of transforming the old language rules to new ones) pages in Mediawiki framework.

Example: page with contents "gylden" ("old English" language) has to be automatically "translated" to "golden" (resulting in "contemporary english" page regeneration if modified). Both pages with "old English" and "contemporary english" have to be accessible using wikipedia-style subdomains and the slugs have to be the same (e.g. en.site.com/slug1 and old-en.site.com/slug1).

The question is if there is any addon that can ease the pain of creation in-house "translation" module or what is the best strategy to start from scratch given the problem description?

Manual "translation" (creation of the pages) can not be a solution due to numerous reasons.

ps. The actual problem is converting pre-reformed Russian cyrillic data to contemporary one and involves dictionary look-ups as well as direct substitution of old characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add your own `Language` subclass with a [LanguageConverter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/LanguageConverter), which handles transliteration and any sort of transformation you want.

See a language converter in action on Serbian: [/**sr-ec**/Главна_страна](https://sr.wikipedia.org/sr-ec/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0) vs. [/**sr-el**/Главна_страна](https://sr.wikipedia.org/sr-el/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Wikipedia-style subdomains are for independent wikis, while you want a single wiki with different representations. Of course you could configure the subdomains to be rewritten to the language converter "directories", but there is no built-in support for that AFAIK.